# How to get a button in a ng-repeat list with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm testing (with e2e test) an APP. My issue is to do a click on a button of a ng-repeat list composed of N repeaters. 
How to get the button of the second row with the class btn-danger (the last one in the code lines below)? (there are a lot of buttons with this class inside the app).

This is a slice of the code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-class="expression" class="ng-scope danger">
    <td class="ng-binding">Info 1</td>
    <td class="ng-binding">Info 2</td>
    <td>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok ng-hide" ng-show="function()"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-class="expression2" popover-html="infoes" popover-trigger="click">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" <="" span=""></span>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-show="function2()" ng-click="function3()" ng-disabled="function4()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-x"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
var item = element.all(by.repeater('cat in cats')).get(0);
    item.element(by.css('button[ng-click="function3()"')).click();
```

Comment: You can also use `first()` in place of `get(0)`.

Comment: `var item = element.all(by.repeater('cat in cats')).get(0);` is the same as `var item = element(by.repeater('cat in cats'))`.

 Did you try using this: `var item = element.all(by.repeater('cat in cats'));      item.element(by.css(".btn btn-xs btn-danger").click();`?
I use a Firebug plugin to help me with css selectors. It's called Firepath.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to your page with chrome, you can inspect the element and get either his selector or his xpath :

[image]

Using that selector you can then select your element (using whatever selector you already use for that purpose).

If you need the second element just select it and the xpath you will get will always point towards the second element. Hope that helped!

Comment: It's not recommended using xpath locator. It can make your tests to be to fragile.

Comment: I totally agree, there are some ways that are way better than this. But I find it useful if you need to start somewhere!